# Java - Installation problem

Tags: java, installation, java-5

I am having the following message while installing JDK 1.5.0_06, 1.5.0_09, etc.

```
"Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library"
Assertion Failed!

Program: C;\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_06\bin\javaw.exe
File:../../../src/share/native/sun/font/t2k/t2kstrm.c
Line:132

Expression: pos<=t->maxPos

For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.


(Press Retry to debug the application - JIT must be enabled)

Abort   Retry    Ignore
```

Whether I press Abort/Retry/Ignore, Dialog box comes again and again.

The additional info I can provide is,

I have had Visual C++ 2005 installed previously, I uninstalled that.

I have .net framework 2.0 installed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is wrong with your fonts, either some font is damaged, or there is a shortcut to a font in the Fonts folder, not the font itself.

Therefore, possible solutions for this problem:

- Check if your Fonts folder has any shortcuts.
- If that doesn't help, start opening fonts one by one. It's not quick, but there's no other way.

Hope this solves your problem.